# Concept checking a function doesn't work with movable-only arguments

Tags: c++, boost, c++-concepts

I have a function that calls a callback function that accepts a movable-only type (for example `unique_ptr`).

```
template <typename Function>
void foo(const Function& function) {
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((
            boost::UnaryFunction<Function, void, std::unique_ptr<Bar>));
    auto bar = std::make_unique<Bar>();
    ...
    function(std::move(bar));
}
```

Trying to compile this code, I get a message that the `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT` line tries to copy the `unique_ptr`. If I remove the line, the code works fine. It seems that the Boost.Concept library does not support move semantics. Is there any workaround for this without writing my own concept class (which, incidentally, would not be very simple to support both lvalues and rvalues as their arguments).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct. Unfortunately, `UnaryFunction` as a concept is written as:

```
  BOOST_concept(UnaryFunction,(Func)(Return)(Arg))
  {
      BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(UnaryFunction) { test(is_void<Return>()); }

   private:
      void test(boost::mpl::false_)
      {    
          f(arg);               // "priming the pump" this way keeps msvc6 happy (ICE)
          Return r = f(arg);
          ignore_unused_variable_warning(r);
      }    

      void test(boost::mpl::true_)
      {    
          f(arg); // <== would have to have std::move(arg)
                  // here to work, or at least some kind of
                  // check against copy-constructibility, etc.
      }    

#if (BOOST_WORKAROUND(__GNUC__, BOOST_TESTED_AT(4) \
                      && BOOST_WORKAROUND(__GNUC__, > 3)))
      // Declare a dummy construktor to make gcc happy.
      // It seems the compiler can not generate a sensible constructor when this is instantiated with a refence type.
      // (warning: non-static reference "const double& boost::UnaryFunction<YourClassHere>::arg"
      // in class without a constructor [-Wuninitialized])
      UnaryFunction();
#endif

      Func f;
      Arg arg; 
  };
```

Since `arg` is passed by lvalue, there's no way to get that to work with Boost.Concepts. Directly. You *could* write a hack though. Since we're just calling checking that `f(arg)` is valid, we could construct a local type for `arg` that is convertible to `unique_ptr<Bar>`. That is:

```
template <typename Function>
void foo(Function f)
{
    struct Foo {
        operator std::unique_ptr<int>();
    };

    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((
            boost::UnaryFunction<Function, void, Foo>));

    f(std::make_unique<int>(42));
}
```

Or more generally:

```
template <typename T>
struct AsRvalue {
    operator T(); // no definition necessary
};

template <typename Function>
void foo(Function f)
{
    BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT((
            boost::UnaryFunction<Function, void, AsRvalue<std::unique_ptr<int>>>));

    f(std::make_unique<int>(42));
}
```

That compiles for me on gcc and clang (though gives a warning on clang about unused typedefs). However, at that point, it may be clearer to just write out your own concept to get it to work. Something like [Piotr's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32013220/2069064) would be easiest.

Comment: Thanks, it works great and is pretty elegant despite being a workaround. Ideally, `UnaryFunction` should check whether `Arg` is an rvalue reference and use `std::move(arg)` it if it is.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename...>
struct voider { using type = void; };

template <typename... Ts>
using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;

template <typename, typename = void_t<>>
struct is_callable : std::false_type {};

template <typename F, typename... Args>
struct is_callable<F(Args...), void_t<decltype(std::declval<F>()(std::declval<Args>()...))>> : std::true_type {};

//...

static_assert(is_callable<Function&(std::unique_ptr<Bar>)>{}, "Not callable");
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/108bcf60f9e0ba6b)

Comment: This one works, but is not as clear as `BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT`. It also doesn't handle return types.